# Блок, заполняющий всё оставшиеся пространство по высоте

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

Как блоку `red` задать высоту, чтоб он заполнял все оставшиеся пространство по высоте? Блок `black` меняет высоту адаптивно, высота `body` равна `100vh`.

[image: макет]

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex; /* становится flex-контейнером */
  flex-direction: column; /* его дети располагаются в столбик */
}

.black {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* чтобы никогда не уменьшался */

  border: 1px dotted #000;
}

.red {
  flex-grow: 1; /* чтобы занимал всё пространство */

  border: 1px dotted #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="black">Black</div>
<div class="red">Red</div>
```